# How to solve the integral in solving this differential equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$$ y' = -x^2y + \tanh(x+3) $$
$$ a(x) = -x^2 $$
$$ A(x) = -x^3/3 $$
$$ y = e^{-x^3/3} \int{e^{x^3/3} \tanh(x+3)\mathrm{d}x} $$

I can't solve this integral. I tried to write $\tanh(x+3)$ as exponential but couldn't solve it anyway.

Comment: I think this integral does not have a closed form solution in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: i have so far tried elementary methods; by parts, converting to exponential, expansion of tanhx, substitutions and i think its safe to say integral has no solutions as elementary function